# How to get the current logged in user name in startup.cs of asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to get the current logged in user name in startup.cs (MVC .NET CORE)

Please let me know if you have any solutions for the same..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that is practical. Why on earth would you need that, additionally -- why are you assuming that anyone is logged in? In the `Startup.cs` the server is literally initializing your application to be served, with that said there is no "logged in" user as this would assume that the app had already issued a login screen -- which means `startup.cs` ran earlier.

Comment: I agree with @DavidPine and would like to add that it appears you have done little to no research before asking this question.

Comment: Agree with you @DavidPine and Brad But my requirement is, I need to capture the user name when ever the user access the application. Application is using windows authentication. hence there is no login page. User directly can go to any page in the application using the url (he may not come directly to home in page). The common page which runs when ever the application is being accessed in startup.cs hence I thought of using it.

Comment: Else I need to add the logging code in all the controllers. Again it will cause another problem that, it will add multiple entries (when ever user refreshes the page and whenever user revisit the page). is there any other page other than startup.cs suitable for this requirement?? Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the Startup class is configuring both the application Dependency Injection container and request pipeline. It is not bound to a request and only executed when the application starts, hence the name *Startup*.

A typical place where you would use the logged in user is [middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) and [controllers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/actions.html).

Comment: Agree with you @Henk. But my requirement is, I need to capture the user name when ever the user access the application. Application is using windows authentication. hence there is no login page. User directly can go to any page in the application using the url (he may not come directly to home in page). The common page which runs when ever the application is being accessed in startup.cs hence I thought of using it.

Comment: Else I need to add the logging code in all the controllers. Again it will cause another problem that, it will add multiple entries (when ever user refreshes the page and whenever user revisit the page). is there any other page other than startup.cs suitable for this requirement?? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is what you are looking for. It is sequential so, if you place your middleware first, your middleware will intercept any request you choose and can prevent access to the rest of the app if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

It must be pointed that the startup.cs is used throughout the life-cycle of the application.
For instance in the Configure method - in the start up.cs - we handle the application errors.

You can retrive user info from within the HTTP context as following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment    
env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500; 
                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        Exception ex = error.Error;
                        var theUser = context.User.Identity.Name;
                      //send email with user name
          //do somehting
                    }
                });
            });
        }

   //part omitted for simplicity
}
```